# python string substitution

Tags: python

Is there a simple way of passing a list as the parameter to a string substitution in python ?
Something like:

`w = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

`s = '%s\t%s\t%s\n' % w`

Something similar to the way dictionaries work in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just convert the list to a tuple:

```
w = ['a', 'b', 'c']
s = '%s\t%s\t%s\n' % tuple(w)
```

Comment: And of course, as fabe said, you can just use a tuple directly.

Comment: It depends from where that data is coming from :-), but yes, theoretically it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

## use a tuple instead of a list

```
w = ('a', 'b', 'c')
s = '%s\t%s\t%s\n' % w
```

## using a dict also works

```
w = { 'Akey' : 'a', 'Bkey' : 'b', 'Ckey' : 'c' }
s = '%(Akey)s\t%(Bkey)s\t%(Ckey)s\n' % w
```

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to use a tuple instead of a list when string's [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) can build the string using a list for you.

`w = ['a', 'b', 'c']
'\t'.join(w) + '\n' # => 'a\tb\tc\n'`